# How can create a view to filter the a list based on the current login user

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, list-view, filter, sharepoint-enterprise

How to create a view based on the current user is in a Person or Group field , this Person or Group field can contain multiple user but not SharePoint Group ,I try to use the contains to filter the data but getting the following error:

[image]

Can someone shine some light on how to create  a filter based on Person or Group? E.G. , I have a Person or Group field called StakeHolders(can contain more than one user) for the current project , How can create  a view to filter the project based on the current login user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To filter a person group column by the current logged in user, use column equals `[Me]`.

Edit to add:
Using equals when a person/group column accepts multiple people still filters properly from my experience.  If you are listed individually, you see the item.  If you are one of 3 people listed, you see the item.  The UI might be saying equals but my theory is the backend XSLT filter is operation like a in or contains for people/group columns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly, though if it's simply based on who the current user us, Eric is right.

If you need to test for group membership, you may need to switch to a DVWP and/or edit the XSL directly. If it's less of a security thing and more for ease of use, you could group by whatever column you want to filter on.

Of course, setting the permissions for each group on each item will act as a filter as well.

Answer (score -1):

[Me] can filter the items for a person logged in

Comment: What PirateEric said 3.5 years ago