# Hide Items added by other Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions

Setting up a military sharepoint, set up a form to allow soldiers to tell us if they have an issue (I.e. pay issue, legal, address change). But I need to hide this information from the other users because it could contain PII.

Answer (score 3):

Under Advanced Settings, you can select under **Read access** "Read items that were created by the user." People who should be able to see all replies need Manage List permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter list view with Created Column By **[Me]**

In this way the user adding data would be able to see data added by him and will not be able to view data added by others

[How can create a view to filter the a list based on the current login user](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24606/how-can-create-a-view-to-filter-the-a-list-based-on-the-current-login-user)

If you need advanced version for filtering by group you can follow this link

[Filtering by a group in a SharePoint Person or Group column](http://www.hornerit.com/2009/07/filtering-by-group-in-sharepoint-person.html)

Edit:

You can add SharePoint workflow on item addition that would impersonate the item and create Item level permission making your list item more secure.

You can use below reference:
[SharePoint workflow list item permission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115187/sharepoint-workflow-list-item-permission)

Comment: This is sort of true. Other users' data would be hidden, but not secured. Usually that works for me, but with PII I prefer to secure rather than obscure. Using this method still allows me to create personal views where I could see everyone's data; you can disable personal views. I'd be able to get the contents of the entire list using scripting. And I could just guess IDs and add them to the URL string.